# Chalice Deploy hangs and then throws timeouts

Tags: python, aws-lambda, chalice

I have a very simple chalice app with a scheduler that I want to deploy to aws lambda. Everything worked fine, however suddenly I cannot deploy the chalice app anymore. It hangs on the line `Creating lambda function: test-dev-periodic_task` for a very long time and then I get the following error message.

```
Creating deployment package.
Reusing existing deployment package.
Updating policy for IAM role: test-dev
Creating lambda function: test-dev-periodic_task
....
....
 line 422, in send
    raise ConnectionClosedError(
botocore.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: Connection was closed before we received a valid response from endpoint URL: "https://lambda.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions".
```

I deleted the lambda function through the aws console but that also didn't fix anything. I am kind of lost how to trouble shoot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it. Apparently my network connection wasn't great. I sat closer to the wifi access point and suddenly it worked. Notice: My internet connection was working the whole time, so it seems `chalice deploy` is a little bit finicky with network issues.